# Haskell Netwire: wires of wires done properly

Tags: haskell, netwire

I am trying to implement a dynamic set of wires in netwire 5 "properly".
I've read the answer to [wires of wires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918915/haskell-netwire-wires-of-wires) question, and I don't particularly like how the code in the example relies on the `Event` converted to a behaviour to show up non-empty on *exactly one execution* of `stepWire`.

So, I want to add and remove wires in the dynamic set via `Event`s, and hopefully without tapping into `Unsafe.Event` or equivalent hackery. Let's drop the removing part for simplicity, and just make it possible to add `Wire`s:

```
dynWireSet1 :: (Monad m, Monoid s)
            => Wire s e m (a, Event (Wire s e m a b)) [b]
```

Each event adds a new wire to the (initially empty) list (or other set) of wires hidden inside, and they all run, all getting the input of type `a`, and have their outputs collected into a list.

The running part is relatively easy, with googleable examples, e.g.:

```
dynWireSet1 = runWires1 []
runWires1 :: (Monad m, Monoid s)
          => [Wire s e m a b]
          -> Wire s e m (a, Event (Wire s e m a b)) [b]
runWires1 wires = mkGen $ \session (input, event) -> do
  stepped <- mapM (\w -> stepWire w session (Right input)) wires
  let (outputs, newwires) = unzip stepped
  return (sequence outputs, runWires1 newwires)
```

Example above ignores events. I suspect that it is impossible
to use the event inside the transition function, other than by
the `event` function from `Unsafe.Event`. Is that correct? I
want to avoid `Unsafe.Event`.

When I step back and look at the *suggested* ways of using events, I see a
function that looks very promising:

```
krSwitch :: Monad m
         => Wire s e m a b
         -> Wire s e m (a, Event (Wire s e m a b -> Wire s e m a b)) b
```

Now, what if I start with simplified runWires:

```
runWires2 :: (Monad m, Monoid s)
          => [Wire s e m a b]
          -> Wire s e m a [b]
runWires2 wires = mkGen $ \session input -> do
  stepped <- mapM (\w -> stepWire w session (Right input)) wires
  let (outputs, newwires) = unzip stepped
  return (sequence outputs, runWires2 newwires)
```

and make dynWireSet a krSwitch:

```
dynWireSet2 :: (Monad m, Monoid s)
            => Wire s e m (a, Event (Wire s e m a b)) [b]
dynWireSet2 = krSwitch (runWires2 []) . second (mkSF_ (fmap addWire))
addWire :: Wire s e m a b -> Wire s e m a [b] -> Wire s e m a [b]
addWire = undefined
```

I am almost there! Now if I only could `fmap` a `(:)` over `runWires2` and get the new wire inserted into `newwires`, I'd be all set! But this is not possible, in general case. In fact, `fmap` over `WGen` just `fmaps` over the output, if I get it right. Useless.

And now, here is my idea. Let's introduce a new variant of `data Wire`, I'll provisionally call it `WCarry g st` because it will carry its internal state in a distinct data type. It's transition function will be of the type

```
((a, c) -> m (b, c))
```

and, given the initial state, the constructor will produce a Wire like this:

```
mkCarry :: Monad m => ((a, c) -> m (b, c)) -> c -> Wire s e m a b
mkCarry transfun state = mkGenN $ \input -> do
  (output, newstate) <- transfun (input, state)
  return (Right output, mkCarry transfun newstate)
```

only introducing `WCarry` type instead of `WGen` type into the resulting wire. It is easy to reformulate `runWires` in terms of `mkCarry`.

Then, fmap instance would look something like this:

```
fmap f (WCarry g st) = WCarry g (fmap f st)
```

It will change the "hidden inside" state object, and we'll be able to use `krSwitch` function meaningfully on this sort of `Wire`s, to tweak their internal state without losing the previous value.

Does this make sense? If what I am trying to do is possible in a simpler way, please advice! If what I am talking about makes sense, how could I go about it? Is is possible to locally extend the `data Wire` definition with WCarry, and extend add the interesting Class instances with corresponding definitions? Any other advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using Netwire and I encountered the exact same problem, so I think it will be useful to answer this. I agree that using (safe) Events is the right way to go. However I don't like adding the `WCarry`, it doesn't seem very intuitive.

You were actually extremely close to the answer. The key to make `addWire` relies in that you don't want to 'modify' the old wire. What you want is create a new wire with the given subwire's output added, so this may be what you were looking for:

```
addWire w ws = fmap (uncurry (:)) (w &&& ws)
```

This wire feeds both wires and then joins the outputs. Hope it helps!

Comment: It works for combining outputs of the existing set and a new wire. But on the next step I will obviously want to _remove_ the wires from the set (using e.g. a map for representation). I can remove unwanted outputs the same way as you suggest, but won't that lead to memory leak?

Comment: Commenting on own comment, perhaps using a lazy map would alleviate the memory leak problem? Would it?

Comment: You can make `w &&& ws` respond to an event that switches back to `ws` when you want to remove `w`.